# One DIV displayed as two columns

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm modifying a WordPress theme that's built upon Bootstrap and would like to get content that will appear in **one** `div` to be distributed over two even height columns. Can this easily be done via the Bootstrap framework or CSS?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is use some of the new CSS3 elements.

Please note that this will only work on the latest browsers and in most cases will require browser prefix's

```css
div {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;/* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
  ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue
  duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
</div>
```

As you can see, you have to call the browser specific calls for `webkit` and `moz`. There's a lot of extra functionality about setting widths and other such information so reading some docs on it will be useful.

Below are a couple of links about how to usage and where its supported

Read more: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)

Browser support: [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)

Answer (score 0):

this is the only available solution with bootstrap :

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/10884/)**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6 lol1">somethink</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6 lol2">somethink</div>
</div>
```

if the content of your `div` is a text you can't manage to display this content in two column , you have to use other `div's` inside this container .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ok, so there is no way to just get the content of one `div` to be spread over two columns? Basically I want to be able to have my client update their details via WordPress and whatever they enter will always span two even height columns. The solution that you've presented would require manually juggling content across the two `div`s until they are equal height, right?

Comment: no whatever the content this will appears in two columns one text to another whatever the screen resolution